# Dual boot /w Win, want to change my Xubuntu to Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, xubuntu

Dual boot /w Win, want to change my Xubuntu to Ubuntu.
What would be the most convenient way to do that? I want the system to be as bloat-free as possible, so I went as far as thinking about formatting Xubuntu completely just to install Ubuntu from scratch.

Also, how would I do that without destroying my Win partitions, and keeping the Grub intact?

Edit:

And what if all I'm doing is changing the DE, does purging xfce4 really removes everything that is unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to switch from Xubuntu to regular Ubuntu desktop. You don't need to format anything, neither to mess with `grub`, so there's any risk.

The core system is the same, so there's no reason to remove it and put it there again.

You just need to install the `ubuntu-desktop` package, and then remove the `xubuntu-desktop` package and its dependencies.

### Switching from one desktop environment to the other

Here's how you can do it (replace `apt` with `apt-get` if running a release prior of Ubuntu 16.04):

1. Open a terminal, and type (it may take a lot of time, since it needs to download and install several packages):

   ```
   sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
   ```
2. Once it's done, remove `xubuntu-desktop` and its dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt purge xubuntu-desktop
   sudo apt autoremove
   ```
3. If everything went fine, run `sudo apt clean` to recover some space and then reboot, so the system will run the new login manager.

With a plain, unmodified system, this should be enough.

---

### Dealing with manually installed packages

Anyways usually you install some more packages to add functionalities to your desktop, and you may don't need them any more after the switch to `ubuntu-desktop`.

Packages that depended on Xfce should already be removed with it, but may be a few packages independent of the desktop environment that you may want to remove.

You can see a list of manually installed packages with the command:

```
apt-mark showmanual
```

Give a look at this list, and if you spot something you remember you installed when using Xubuntu and that you think won't need any more, remove it and its dependencies with something like:

```
sudo apt purge packagename
sudo apt autoremove
```

Obviously, don't remove packages if `apt` tells you that they are dependencies of the `ubuntu-desktop` package.

If you don't remember what a package does, you can get a description with:

```
apt show packagename
```

If unsure, leave a package as it is. If unused, it won't do any harm, apart from taking a little space on your drive.

Comment: Isn't `apt` the older package manager of the two? I tried running the commands but for some reason, even **after** rebooting the system, I still have Xubuntu (even though trying to purge it again tells me I have no such package). Very strange!

Comment: Oh, I just change to "Other" and it let me to login, with the same login, but this time into Ubuntu! Unfortunately, I still see Xubuntu icons on login, though. I guess a clean install is my only chance...

Comment: Probably some of the files related to your previous sessions are still there. Don't worry, they won't hurt. Some of them are in your home directory, tracking your last used DE, some of them are system wide.

Comment: As said above, it's also possible that some Xfce related packages were marked as "manually installed". Give a look at `apt-mark showmanual` and remove some of them. You can also try to remove some [packages required by xubuntu-desktop](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/xubuntu-desktop) such as `xfce4-panel` and `xfce4-session` and then use `apt autoremove` to trigger the removal of related packages (answer yes when prompted to remove them!). Anyways, those files won't harm your system. Don't be paranoic. There's nothing "dirty". This is not Windows, you don't need to format and reinstall.